# Is it acceptable to solicit answer from university?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, university

I have applied to a master's degree.

If the first screening is successful, we are supposed to have an interview in March before the final decision.

The result from the first screening were supposed to come in during the month of February.. Is it acceptable from me to solicit an answer from the university?

I am scared by this test and I am studying a lot to pass it, so I would like to know as soon as possible when is the interview.. I expected the answer to come in mid-februrary so to allow us some time to prepare for the travel to the university and to review everything. (I am studying nonetheless, but it would be nice to at least have some date)

I don't want to come off bad with professors or whoever it is that is handling the email but I would really like to know for sure.

Is it too early? Can you suggest when it would be appropriate?

Please notice that the interview should be held in March and I am studying in the meantime (I just finished my regular mid-year exams at my current university and courses will soon start again, so this is particularly harsh for me).
I just don't want to study until the 20th of march to eventually be told that I have not survived the first screening!

Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If their own deadline has passed, yes, you can ask. Send a polite email to whoever is handling the admission. As long as you don't *demand* it, no one will take offence.

There are many reasons why you wouldn't have received an answer, but note that some institutions, as a policy, never notify rejected candidates (ESA is among the worst at this, they never tell, even the candidates that have been interviewed).

Best of luck.